# Freeradius3 auth with OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap, freeradius

For the past few days, i've been trying to configure freeradius to authenticate wifi clients in OpenLDAP (without TLS - 389 bind).

I tried several guides and did not get the result i was looking for.

At localhost, RADTEST works and i receive an Accept-Accpet.
User is found within LDAP and accepts authentication.

When i try to authenticate via wifi (Windows 10), i can't connect.

The configuration i am currently using is this:

https://gitlab.com/ae-dir/client-examples/-/blob/master/freeradius/radiusd.conf

Someone with experience integrating freeradius with openldap?

I need wifi clients to connect with their ldap credentials.

Comment: Hi, i'm also working on Freeradius and OpenLdap recently. So does your freeradius server open the port 1812? Because last time, that's how I solve external radius authentication

Comment: Yes. Only work local with radtest. External mschap/gtc/pap doesn't work.

Comment: And then, does your server's firewall allow inbound connection from port 1812?

Comment: Firewall disabled. Can see Reject-Reject on logs... Can't setup to work. Try more than five guides, and same issues.

Comment: I see, What about you debug the freeradius? What does the Debugger said? Last time, I debug it and the problem was Ldap Require password and CHAP did not pass the password

Answer (score 0):

You have not explained more details about the authentication method you are trying to use. This is important. However, a simple recipe for making freeradius+ldap authentication work with Windows10, Ubuntu and Android in EAP/TTLS mode is as follows:

1. Make sure the radius server has access to the LDAP server. Also make sure that the clients (access points) have access to the radius server. Check firewall issues and freeradius configuration (for Debian10 the file is **/etc/freeradius/3.0/clients.conf**)
2. For the authentication test (taking into account that the previous step has already been certified by you), there are two interesting tools: **radtest** (part of the freeradius-utils package) which does not support EAP/TTLS authentication, and a tool called **eapol_test**, which is part of the wpa_supplicant package and supports EAP-TTLS.
3. Follow the EAP/TTLS configuration steps and how to use the **eapol_test** tool on this [link](https://openschoolsolutions.org/freeradius-secure-wifi-network/).
4. Make sure you **generate the new certificates** (don't use snakeoil certificates at all) and **don't forget to change the certificate settings** in /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/eap). The link from the previous step does not talk about this step.
5. Run freeradius in full debug mode to find any errors (ie **freeradius -X**).
6. Don't forget to [check](http://deployingradius.com/documents/protocols/compatibility.html) the password and protocol compatibility list.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this steps!

But, can't access.

Comment: Veja meu log na outra resposta.